# Why does my computer show multiple terminals open Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: command-line, c

I am running a c program that records the number of terminals open and then lists them but when I run it I am shown multiple terminal windows open when only the one is, why?

Comment: "I have this thing that something... why?"  See how vague and unanswerable that is?

Comment: `w` may do something similar - `pts` *(Pseudo terminal slave)* are usually terminals, `tty` *(teletypewriter)* are the text interfaces you get by pressing Ctrl-Alt then F2, F3 etc. It may be just showing background programs, or the thing that the C program is running in etc.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that there *are* many "terminals" open. Try hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1-6</kbd>. These are called [TTY terminal sessions](http://mostlylinux.wordpress.com/troubleshooting/ttysessions/).